# select values on multiple data frames by multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I am trying to run a function that takes value1, value2, value3 of the same time and name from multiple data frames. `output <- function(value1, value2, value3)` For example:

```
DF1:
time       name      value1
Jan 1990      1      4
Feb 1990      1      2
Mar 1990      1      3
Jan 1990      2      2
Feb 1991      2      1
DF2:
time       name      value2
Jan 1990      1      4
Feb 1990      1      2
Mar 1990      1      3
Jan 1990      2      2
Feb 1991      2      1
DF3:
time       name      value3
Jan 1990      1      4
Feb 1990      1      2
Mar 1990      1      3
Jan 1990      2      2
Feb 1991      2      1
```

Should I use join and then apply on each row?

```
output
time       name    output 
Jan 1990      1      4
Feb 1990      1      2
Mar 1990      1      3
Jan 1990      2      2
Feb 1991      2      1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

**Option 1: dplyr**
    library(dplyr)

```
output <- inner_join(inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("time", "name")), 
                 df3, by=c("time", "name"))
```

**Option 2: plyr**

```
library(plyr)
join_all(list(df1,df2,df3), by=c('time','name'), type='inner')
```

**Option 3: Base R merge+reduce**

Use `merge` + `reduce` - credits to @akrun

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c("time","name"), all.x=TRUE), list(df1,df2,df3))
```

**Output**

```
      time name value1
1 Jan 1990    1      4
2 Feb 1990    1      2
3 Mar 1990    1      3
4 Jan 1990    2      2
5 Feb 1991    2      1
```

You can then rename the columns as per your necessity.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I have let's say 10 DFs. Is there a way of using `Reduce`?  Also, I need all of value 1, value 2 and value 3. So I just rewrite `by = c("time", "name")`. Correct?

Comment: @YellowRiver added more options pls check